# Latex not formatted under review tab

Tags: discussion, bug, status-completed

I'm not sure if this is a bug or expected behavior, but I find it a little hard to do reviews for posts including Latex.

Basically when I go to the *review* screen and see the list of all possible posts to review, the posts show just fine with the Latex correctly formatted.

But when I click on "review answer" and it expands the post, I find the Latex code shows up raw with no formatting, and the \$...\$ appear. This makes it hard to review if you want to verify some equations or check that the OP formatted his Latex correctly.

Any thoughts, is this expected behavior, or a bug?

Comment: As a workaround, click on the question title to get taken directly to the question.  Your actions will still be captured to keep track of your review.  When you're done with that page, click the `review` button again or just go back a page in your browser.

Comment: How about a fix to the system instead of just doing a "work-around?"

Comment: Not to offer another workaround, but see [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129014/) to an MSO post on this topic.  You can use a bookmarklet to render it while in review.

Answer (score 1):

The new review system solves this issue and renders MathJax correctly.